# Does JavaScript support verbatim strings?

Tags: javascript, string

In C# you can use verbatim strings like this:

```
@"\\server\share\file.txt"
```

Is there something similar in JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't support for that in JavaScript. And that workaround seems very problematic as you now lose the ability to have forward slashes.

I've run into this issue myself when I needed to build an alert message or something from an ASP.NET back end, and stick it in a JavaScript alert on the front end. The issue was that developers could enter anything in the Page.Alert() method.

What I did to solve this was as follows:

```
public void Alert(string message)
{
    message = message.Replace("\\", "\\\\")
        .Replace("\r\n", "\n")
        .Replace("\n", "\\n")
        .Replace("\t", "\\t")
        .Replace("\"", "\\\"");

    // and now register my JavaScript with this safe string.
}
```

Comment: It was only an example, well suited to the given question (Windows path). You can replace / by any character.

Comment: It doesn't actually answer the question, which is "how to avoid expanding escape sequences in string literals".

Answer (score 17):

**Template strings** do support line breaks.

```
`so you can
do this if you want`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

It does not of course prevent expansion from occurring the in the text, and by extension, code execution but maybe that's a good thing?

> **Note:** I don't think there's a way to take an existing string and run it through expression interpolation. This makes it impossible to inject code this way since the code has to originate in the source. I don't know of an API that can do expression interpolation on-demand.
>
> **Note 2:** Template strings are a ES2015 / ES6 feature. Support in every browser except (wait for it...) IE! However, Edge does support template strings.
>
> **Note 3:** Template strings expand escape sequences, if you have a string inside a string that string will expand its escape sequences.
>
> ```
> `"A\nB"`
> ```
>
> ...will result in:
>
> ```
> "A
> B"
> ```
>
> ...which will not work with `JSON.parse` because there's now a new-line in the string literal. Might be good to know.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I needed a quick way to get character codes for testing and this worked well.

Comment: It doesn't actually answer the question, which is "how to avoid expanding escape sequences in string literals".

Answer (score 13):

Just use `String.raw()`

```
String.raw`\n`
```

will output

```
\\n
```

---

But I don't know how to solve the case:

```
String.raw`hello`hello`  // It will throw an TypeError
String.raw`hello\`hello` // Output is 'hello\\`hello'
```

I don't know how to deal with `` ` `` :(

Comment: ```String.raw`hello${"`"}hello`
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a very old thread, but still here's a workaround:

```
function verbatim(fn){return fn.toString().match(/[^]*\/\*\s*([^]*)\s*\*\/\}$/)[1]}
```

Which you will use as this:

```
var myText = verbatim(function(){/*This
 is a multiline \a\n\0 verbatim line*/})
```

Basically what happens here is that js treats comments indeed as verbatim strings. Furthermore, these are store along with the function. So what happens here is that we create a function with some verbatim comments which we extract in the verbatim function.

Comment: I don't know why there's all the talk about escaping characters and replacing strings as that seems like the opposite of verbatim - though the OP compared between programming and JS he didn't state he needed interoperability between them. This answer works in an elegant and surprising way - it kind of brightened my day! But just copying the JS gave me the error "Unable to get property '1' of undefined or null reference". Changing the return statement to `return fn.toString().split("/*")[1].split("*/")[0]` to get only everything between the comments did what I need. with thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can use static [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw).It was introduced in ECMAScript 6 (ES6). This is similar to the r prefix in Python, or the @ prefix in C# for string literals.

This is used to get the raw string form of template strings (that is the original, uninterpreted text).

Syntax:

```
String.raw(callSite, ...substitutions)
or 
String.raw`template string`
```

Example:

```
const filePath_SimpleString = 'C:\\Development\\profile\\aboutme.html';
const filePath_RawString = String.raw`C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html`;
  
console.log(`The file was uploaded from: ${filePath}`);
console.log(`The file was uploaded from: ${filePath}`);
 
// expected output will be same: 
//"The file was uploaded from: C:\Development\profile\aboutme.html"
```

Answer (score 3):

Big kludge of a workaround...

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function foo() {
    var string = document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML;
    alert(string);
}
window.onload=foo;
</script>
<style>
#foo{
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Calling foo on page load.
<div id="foo">\\server\path\to\file.txt</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has numerous side effects, you better hope there is no & in your string.

Comment: @Juan Mendes: What part of "Big kludge" didn't you understand?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "A kludge (or kluge) is a workaround, a quick-and-dirty solution, a clumsy or inelegant, **yet effective**..." Your solution produces wrong results with simple input, doesn't even qualify as a kludge.

Comment: Just to back up Mr. Muskrat here... I have a situation where I'm guaranteed not to have an & in my innerHTML (or other HTML symbols for that matter), and this is an effective quick-and-dirty solution which turns out to be pretty easy.

Comment: Doesn't qualify as a verbatim example imo.

Answer (score 2):

I'll re-iterate what's been said before - verbatim strings aren't possible in javascript.  It's actually easy to escape valid escape characters like `\n \\ \t` etc but the problem comes from escaping non-valid characters due to the way they are handled in the different functions they become incompatible.  For example

```
"\a".replace("\a","\\a")     // WORKS \a
"aa\a".replace("\a", "\\a")  // FAILS \aaa
```

Also if you look at an array of illegal special characters eg `["\a"]` the character will just look like an `a`.  This makes doing what you want essentially impossible.

Hope that at least clears it up for you.