# JavaScript textContent display special characters

Tags: javascript, html

Given string `var str = "foo \n bar"` how do I render it in HTML so it's displayed exactly as is - `foo \n bar`.

If I put this string into DIV using `textContent` or `innerHTML` I get `"foo bar"`. PRE will display `"foo"` on 1st line and `" bar"` on 2nd line.

Do I have to manually escape every special character or there is CSS rule or HTML tag to do it for me?

Comment: Do you want the '\n' to actually be shown in the HTML (i.e like `foo \n bar`) or do you want the current HTML to be presented in two different lines, like first `foo`, then ` bar`?

Comment: I've gotten great use out of this answer for my purely client side stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35681749/862660

Comment: I ended up doing `JSON.stringify(str).slice(1).slice(0, -1)`